# How do i count total number of distinct elements in a column of MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database

i have  a table named city in my database and 
I have tried using the`select  distinct count(*) from city`
but it's not returning the answer that is required

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect the problem you are facing so that you can learn too rather than just copying out the solution.

You have to find out the distinct entries from a particular column in a table.
You would use the DISTINCT clause. [Refer](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-distinct)

> MySQL DISTINCT clause is used to remove duplicate records from the table and fetch only the unique records. The DISTINCT clause is only used with the SELECT statement.

```
Syntax:

SELECT DISTINCT expressions  
FROM tables  
[WHERE conditions];
```

Now you want to count the distinct entries from a column
so you can just use the count clause with distinct clause enclosed in it.

For example -

```
select count(distinct columnname) 
from tablename
```

Comment: **Thanks for the clear explanation!**.I had it working properly

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` for the column that you want the result:

```
select count(distinct columnname) 
from city
```